# Rails array how to multiply a column with a number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my Taletids table:

```
Price (integer)
Price2(integer)
```

In my view I have:

```
@taletids = Taletid.where(:online => true).order('position')
```

But I want to multiply the price column with 2.

And add a "fake" column to the `@taletids` array sum with is the sum of the Price2 multiplied with `2 (params[:tal])` and the Price column.

So that I can call the sum in view as this:

```
<% @taletids.each do |tale| %>
  <%= tale.sum %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a method to your Taletids model representing sum:

```
class Taletids < ActiveRecord::Base
  def sum
    self.Price + (self.Price2 * 2)
  end

  def sum_x(x)
    self.Price + (self.Price2 * x)
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is just the number it should multipli with is based on a param

Comment: Is it smart to make the multiply with a helper then_

Comment: You could give sum a parameter if you like.  (I've added an example to my answer).  It's just a normal method.  As far as best practices, I'm not sure I know the answer to whether a helper would be better in this case.

Comment: The problem is just the calculation would be very large and ugly with a viewhelper see here http://pastie.org/private/pjrfbaasxbtn1eidfeolya. And I want to show the talkprice, smsprice in view. So it would take another view helper and another calculation.

Comment: Thinking more about it, view helpers are for presentation.  I would put calculations associated with the data itself in the model as I have shown.  If you need to, you could add a new attribute to Taletids and only do the calculation once on initialization.  Multiplying by 2 isn't a lot of overhead unless you are calling this method thousands of times.

Comment: How should I use the sum_x method in the controller? How to define x? :) Example setting x to params[:tal] and then call it in view taletid.sum

Comment: How is it possible to call in controller example: @taletids.tal = Taletid.sum_tal(4) which gives this error: undefined method `sum_tal' for #<Class:0x473dfa8>

Comment: @taletids.sum_tal(4)  -  it's an instance method, not a class method as you have written it.

Comment: I have tried @taletids.tal = @taletids.sum_tal(4) error: undefined method `sum_tal' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3b3b098 - PS how to create a class method instead :]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6026/discussion-between-matt-hulse-and-rails-beginner)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can add a method to your Taletid model (app/models/taletid.rb) which does the computation you want.

```
def sum
    (price2 * 2) + price
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is just the number it should multipli with is based on a param